# SSRS 2008 Reports column and row header visibility while scrolling

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

For the tablix used in report keep header visible while scrolling options are selected for row and column headers during design time. Scrolling is happening during testing time on report server also. During deployment, the reports are hosted on a report viewer control in asp.net page. Auto scrolling is not happening. As the report's size is bigger, auto scrolling is essential. Please provide guidance to over come this problem. Thanks in advance